# CMake 'no rule to make target' with external library

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, libevent

I am trying link one of my programs to [libevent](https://github.com/libevent/libevent). I am using CMake as build system. My project structure is as follows:

```
my_project
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── README.md
├── build
│   └── Build stuff
└── software
    ├── README.md
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    ├── libraries
    │   ├── libevent
    │   │   └── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── anotherlibrary
    │       └── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── prog1
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── prog2
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── prog3
        └── CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeList.txt of prog1 (the one that's needs to be linked to libevent)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project (prog1)

file(GLOB prog1
    "*.h"
    "*.cpp"
)

include_directories("${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR}/libevent/include")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${prog1})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} event_core)
```

But when I build the project make can't find the library build by libevent. it searched for: `libraries/libevent/lib/libevent_core.a` this is the wrong path since libevent builds it libs inside: `my_project/build/software/libraries/libevent/lib/libevent_core.a`

How do I tell CMake to search there for the library? I already added the following lines to my Cmake file but this wasn't working

```
    link_directories(/my_project/build/software/libraries/libevent/lib/)

    SET(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib)
    SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin)
```

Anyone a suggestion?

Comment: `link_directories` accepts *directory* with a library file, not a full path to that file. So comman should be called as `link_directories(/my_project/build/software/libraries/libevent/lib)`.

Comment: From your file structure it's not clear if this is one CMake project. The shown `prog1/CMakeLists.txt` hints you have multiple projects. Could you add the content of your root `CMakeLists.txt` file for clarification? I would recommend to have only one project or - if you don't mind building the libraries several times - include the CMake dependencies of `prog1` into its `CMakeList.txt`. Something like `add_subdirectory(../libraries/libevent libevent)` and then make your executable depend on it with `add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} event_core)`. CMake will then take care of the linking part.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it was a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself by removing the content from the `build` directory and re running `cmake ..` inside the `build` directory.

I think CMake was somehow not aware of the changes I made and by rebuilding the project the problem was fixed.